# Reset ealier install with apt-get

Tags: debian, apt

By mistake I installed `apache2` together with `phpmyadmin`.

I have now removed everything but when I want to install `phpmyadmin` I'm forced to install `apache2` too.

How to reset this setting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`phpmyadmin`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/phpmyadmin) depends on

```
libapache2-mod-php5 | libapache2-mod-php5filter | php5-cgi | php5-fpm | php5
```

By default, if none of the dependencies is already installed, the first dependency is chosen, which leads to the installation of `apache2` (`libapache2-mod-php5` depends on `apache2`). If you don’t want this to happen, you need to choose one of the other dependencies and specify that at the same time as `phpmyadmin`.

Of the 5 options listed:

- `libapache2-mod-php5` and `libapache2-mod-php5filter` are Apache  modules and depend on `apache2`.
- `php5` is just a dependency package with much the same dependencies as `phpmyadmin`.

So that leaves `php5-cgi` and `php5-fpm` as your options if you want `phpmyadmin` without `apache2`. Which one you want will depend on your web server setup.

For example:

```
apt-get install phpmyadmin php5-cgi
```

Comment: how do you get this information? command? :)

Comment: `apt-cache show phpmyadmin`, or the [packages site](https://packages.debian.org).

Comment: This answer started out ok but then went off the rails because "php5" is just a dependency package. I have proposed an edit to fix it.